# Nesting :json include in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, json

I have three models:

```
class A < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :bs
end

class B < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :c
  belongs_to :a
end

class C < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :b
end
```

I want to get json data containing all B's and C's for an A. I tried a number of things similar to:

```
render json: @as, :include => [:bs => [:include=>[:c]]
```

but nothing works. What would be a good way to do this.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Refer to [`ActiveModel::Serializers::JSON#as_json`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/Serializers/JSON/as_json) to see the options you can pass to `render :json`. To quote:

> To include associations use `:include` ...
>
> Second level and higher order associations work as well:
>
> ```ruby
> user.as_json(:include => { :posts => {
>                              :include => { :comments => {
>                                              :only => :body } },
>                              :only => :title } })
> # => { "id": 1, "name": "Konata Izumi", "age": 16,
> #      "created_at": "2006/08/01", "awesome": true,
> #      "posts": [ { "comments": [ { "body": "1st post!" }, { "body": "Second!" } ],
> #                   "title": "Welcome to the weblog" },
> #                 { "comments": [ {"body": "Don't think too hard" } ],
> #                   "title": "So I was thinking" } ]
> #    }
> ```

It's not necessary to call `to_json` or `as_json` directly, as `render :json` does it automatically.

Comment: If you're stuck in Rails 2, `render()` doesn't support `:include`, but `to_json()` does. In that case, it makes sense to call `render :json => @as.to_json(:include => :bs)`.

Comment: to_json sometimes break the nest struct

Comment: @Albert.Qing If you're having a specific problem you should post it as a new question.

Comment: @Jordan [Here is Question about this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33648503/how-to-render-json-with-include-association-model)

Answer (score 9):

You need to pass in hash instead of array

```
render :json => @as.to_json(:include => { :bs => {:include =>:c} })
```

Answer (score 6):

For those looking to do the same thing but with ruby's new syntax instead, it would be something like this

```
render json: @as.to_json(include: { bs: { include: :c}})
```

And to extract only some attributes:

```
render json: @a.to_json(only: [:name, :phone, :phone_mobile], include: { bs: { only: :email, include: {c: {only: [:id, :name]}}}})
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
render :json => @as.to_json(:include => {:bs => :c})
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
render json: @tiquets, :include => { :enterprise => {:include => { :location => {:only => :lo_name } },:only => :en_name } } }
```

Comment: @OwaisKureshi A code-only answer might not be a good one, but it's still an answer. I would recommend you this post about the LQPRQ: [You're doing it wrong: A plea for sanity in the Low Quality Posts queue](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287563/youre-doing-it-wrong-a-plea-for-sanity-in-the-low-quality-posts-queue)

Comment: @FelixSFD , Well I agree, but there should be some text explaining the answer, or he can just post this as a comment?

Comment: @OwaisKureshi It's recommended and preferable to explain the code a bit. But even without explanation, this is an answer.

Comment: @FelixSFD Alright I got your point, thanks for explaining, I have retracted my comment.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
render json: @as.to_json(include:{bs: {include:{c:}}})
```