# Rails, including relationships in json render

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

I have the following code which returns a json with some data that includes @admin_user.companies:

```
@admin_user = User.find_by_email(email)

render :json=>{:status=>{:code=>200,:token=>@admin_user.authentication_token,
    :user=> @admin_user,
    :companies => @admin_user.companies }}
```

Each company also have many "locations". How do I include all the locations for every single company in @admin_user.companies in the json?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9983436/nesting-json-include-in-rails

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The conventional way is to use

```
render json: @admin_user.companies, include: :locations
```

(Please refer to [`#as_json`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/Serializers/JSON/as_json) for more options.)

You don't need to include the status code in your JSON, since it's already in the HTTP headers. Thus, the following might get you close to what you need.

```
render :json => @admin_user,
  :include => {
    :companies => { :include => :locations },
  },
  :methods => :authentication_token
```

#### Side Note

This is just an example. You will have to configure `:include` and `:methods` to get exactly what you want. For even more fine-grained control, look into [JBuilder](https://github.com/rails/jbuilder) or [RABL](https://github.com/nesquena/rabl).

Comment: It doesn't give me any errors, but the json only returns companies, and methods. Is it missing something? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Probably. Have you tried debugging it? It works as expected on a test app I just made.

Comment: I did and this worked render json: @admin_user, :include => { :companies => {:include =>:locations} }

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to use [jbuilder](https://github.com/rails/jbuilder) which allows you much finer-grained control over how your JSON is generated:

- Add the `jbuilder` gem to your app
- Use `JBuilder.encode` from your controllers to generate JSON
- Alternatively, create `.json.jbuilder` templates in your `views` directories