# Simple includes() is not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the following scope:

This is product.rb:

```
    has_one :current_price, -> {
    where('prices.id = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM prices p2 WHERE product_id = prices.product_id)') 
  }, class_name: 'Price'
```

I'm trying to get the current price of a specific product and I'm getting the product data without the `include()`.

This is product_controller.rb:

```
  def current_price
    @product = Product.includes(:current_price).where("id = ?", params[:id])
    respond_to do |format|
      format.json { render :json => @product }
    end
  end
```

For example, Im getting this JSON:

```
{"id":10,"name":"Corneta Minipill","created_at":"2015-11-25T19:49:37.000-04:30","updated_at":"2015-11-25T19:49:37.000-04:30","published":null}
```

Im specting the same JSON adding current_price result, for example:

```
{"id":10,"name":"Corneta Minipill","created_at":"2015-11-25T19:49:37.000-04:30","updated_at":"2015-11-25T19:49:37.000-04:30","published":null,"current_price":"2000"}
```

I used the same `includes()` before and it works.

I already tried replacing `includes()` with `joins()` and `eager_load()`.

What is happening?

Comment: What do you mean "is not working". We need sample input, expected output, and what you're getting. Please read "[ask]" and edit the question providing the missing information.

Comment: Please check the updates, ty!

Comment: "Im specting" isn't clear. You're "expecting"? "Im" is spelled "I'm".

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9983436/nesting-json-include-in-rails

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`ActiveRecord::QueryMethods.includes`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/includes) only eager loads the associations.

It does not however change the serialized respresentation of the models,  so the associated models will not be auto-magically included in the serialized result - you will have to [pass](http://www.tigraine.at/2011/11/17/rails-to_json-nested-includes-and-methods)  the includes option to the `to_json` method as well.

Comment: THANK YOU VERY MUCH! You're right, I was losing the current price on the JSON! Thanks

Comment: You are welcome. If you were able to get the code to work, consider accepting the answer using the check button. In case you have any auxiliary questions, please feel free to ask in the comments.