# Rails with JSON Api - including has_many relationships

Tags: ruby-on-rails, include, has-many, json-api

I have three models, Item and Transfer and Category (aka Item Type):

```
class Item < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :category
  has_many :transfers
end

class Transfer < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :item
end

class Category < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :item
end
```

In my controller, I have

```
render json: @item, include: %i[transfer category]
# FWIW the include doesn't seem to affect category at all...
```

Which results in a JSON Api payload which takes the following shape:

```
{
  data: {
      id,
      attributes: {
        /* the other attributes */
        transfers: [ { /* full transfer object */ } ]
      },
      relationships: {
        category: { data: { id, type: 'categories' } },
        transfers: { data: [ { /* full transfer object */ } ]
      }
    }
  },
  included: [ { type: 'category', id, attributes } ]
}
```

The categories are behaving how I expect them to. How do I get it so that each `transfer` is included in the `included` array instead of nested in the attributes or in the relationships?

Thank you!

Edit: not a duplicate. I'm not attempting to nest responses, just included them in the `included` section to be compliant with the JSON API spec. Anyway, I figured it out, and an answer will be forthcoming shortly!

Comment: Try using `transfers` instead of `transfer`.

Comment: Thanks @Gerry that was a typo. Fixed. Still doesn't work though :/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Nesting :json include in Rails](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9983436/nesting-json-include-in-rails)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was missing a `TransferSerializer`! Once I added one, it was put in the `included` array like you'd expect.

Comment: where did you add it?

Answer (score 1):

I think, this question is kinda duplicated. Check this out: [Nesting :json include in Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9983436/nesting-json-include-in-rails)

You need to use `as_json` and nested `include`.

Comment: I've tried various forms of 
    render json: @item, include: { category: true, transfers: { include: :id } }
with no luck :/